# Passing phone country code from Clickfunnels to Webinarjam

Tags: javascript, intl-tel-input

I've used `intl-tel-input` inside clickfunnels to let the users pick their phone country code, I'm passing the phone country code into the input directly while +1(US) being the default, for example: +15035555555 is being submitted. On submission, only the phone number is being passed to webinarjam while the country code is being ignored. Why is this happening? I tried to reach both webinarjam and clickfunnels to find a solution and webinarjam told us to contact clickfunnels while clickfunnels told us to check in the Facebook group (I still didn't get accepted in it). So if someone has faced any similar issue, please help.